# True/false Question: Is every maximal ideal of $C(X,\mathbb{R})$ is equal to $I(x)$ for some $x\in X$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $X=(0,1)$ be the open unit interval and $C(X,\mathbb{R})$ be the ring of continuous functions from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$ , for any $x\in (0,1)$, let  $I(x)=\{f\in C(X,\mathbb{R} | f(x)=0\}$.

Is the following statement is true/false ?

Every maximal ideal of $C(X,\mathbb{R})$ is equal to $I(x)$ for some $x\in X$

as I read the  Books *Topics in Algebra* by Herstein. I think  by Herstein algebra,  it will be true

Is it true ?

Answer (score 4):

No, the set of all functions of compact support is an ideal of $C(X)$, and by Zorn's lemma is contained in a maximal ideal $J$; this ideal is not of the form $I(x)$.

Comment: can u elaborate more  @LOrd shark sir

Answer (score 2):

To add to Shark's answer: this set forms an ideal $J$. It is contained in some maximal ideal. To prove that this isn't of the form $I(x)$: For every $x \in (0;1)$ there is a function $f$ with compact support such that $f(x)=1$. Thus, for $f \notin I(x)$. Thus, $J$ isn't a subset of $I(x)$ for any  $x$. Thus, the maximal ideal isn't a $I(x)$.

Comment: Also putting the topology of local uniform convergence on $C(0,1)$, the closure of the ideal $J$  *(of continuous functions supported on closed intervals $[a,b] \subset (0,1)$)* is the whole ring $C(0,1)$ thus for a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m} \supset J$ the homomorphism $C(0,1) \to C(0,1) / \mathfrak{m} \to \Bbb{C} $ won't be continuous.